# how to create a custom attribute that stop the invocation of a method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create on c# an attribute that will check some parameters before the invocation of a method  and will stop the method from being invoke if something wrong.

something like this

```js
   [TestMethod]
   public void somemethod ()
   {
      .....
   }

   public class TestMethodAttribute : Attribute
   {
       public bool testParameters()
       {
          if(a==b)
            return false;
           else
             return false;
      }
   }
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem with doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to inherit **ActionFilterAttribute  (System.Web.Mvc)** class and override the   OnActionExecuting method. Keep in mind that "OnActionExecuting " method is  Called by the ASP.NET MVC framework ***before*** the action method you called for executing.

```
public class TestMethodIfLoggedIn : ActionFilterAttribute
   {
     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
       {
         base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
         var a = HttpContext.Current.Session["a"];
         var b = HttpContext.Current.Session["b"];

       if(a.ToString() == b.ToString())
        { 
           HttpContext.Current.Session["Message"] = "A = B";
        }
     else    
         {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Message"] = "A is not equal to b";
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Desired_Controller_Name",
                action = "ActionName"
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using webforms on my project and not mvc. the OnActionExecuting is not firing. Do you know how can I implement this  on .net webforms?

Answer (score 0):

If you use DI containers, such as Unity. You can intercept the method invocation.

```
install-package Unity.Interception
```

Configure DI container, something like this:

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<ICustomType, CustomType>(
   new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>(),
   new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>());
```

Define the attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class TestMethodAttribute : HandlerAttribute
{
    public override ICallHandler CreateHandler(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        return new TestMethodHandler();
    }
}
```

Add interception logic:

```
public class TestMethodHandler : ICallHandler
{
    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
    {
        //manipulate with method here 
        //getNext is a method delegate 
        IMethodReturn result = getNext()(input, getNext);
        return result;
    }
}
```